# Add Calendar to ComboBox

Tags: powershell, combobox, calendar

I am creating a form to onboard new users and I want the techs to be able to select the end date for the AD account. If there is no end date selected then the expiration is set to unlimited. I am trying to add a calendar to a combobox but it won't appear.

I have tried using DateTimePicker instead but that does not allow me to edit the date in the text field nor does it allow to me to choose no date at all

```
$box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$box.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(130,390)
$box.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,30)
$box.DropDownHeight = 200

$calendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
$calendar.ShowTodayCircle = $false
$calendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1 

$box.Items.Add($calendar)
```

I would like to have the combobox show the calendar in the dropdown when the arrow is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of examples of how you could implement this. WPF is more elegant but your are using WinForms so, it's not as flexible.

You could try and consider one of the below:

[Difference between Calendar & Date Picker control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569606/difference-between-calendar-date-picker-control-in-wpf)

[Working with WPF Calendar](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-calendar-control)

[Drop down Date Range Picker](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/817b80e7-3ed8-42d9-9e99-a8f6352b3965/drop-down-date-range-picker)

All-in-all though, your query is a duplicate of this but this is for WPF and you are using WinForm....

[How do I get DatePicker and TextBox information from XAML into a Powershell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529399/how-do-i-get-datepicker-and-textbox-information-from-xaml-into-a-powershell-vari)

A WinForm approach would be something like this...

[Two Calendar Controls for PowerShell](https://adminscache.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/two-calendar-guis-for-powershell/)

The code samples for the above are too long to post here. So, hit those and copy paste as needed.

Or this

[Hey, Scripting Guy! Can Windows PowerShell Alleviate My Need to Type Dates?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-can-windows-powershell-alleviate-my-need-to-type-dates)

```
Get-DatePickerFunction.ps1 
Function Get-DatePicker 
{   
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) | 
    Out-Null 

    $WinForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form   
    $WinForm.text = “DatePicker Control”   
    $WinForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(205,55) 

    $DatePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker   
    #$DatePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom 
    #$DatePicker.CustomFormat = “MM-dd-yyyy” 
    $WinForm.Controls.Add($DatePicker)   

    $WinForm.Add_Shown($WinForm.Activate())  
    $WinForm.showdialog() | Out-Null  
    $DatePicker.value 
} #end function Get-DatePicker 

# *** Entry point to script *** 

# Get-EventLog -LogName application -After [datetime](Get-Datepicker) # Windows PowerShell 2.0 call 
# wps 1.0 version of call 
$dte = [datetime](Get-DatePicker) 
Get-EventLog -LogName application | 
Where-Object { $_.timeWritten -gt $dte }
```

As for not picking a date at all. Set it to null Unless you make this mandatory, you should allow just skipping of the entry. The examples above show that a value return can be optional.

Comment: Are you setting the MinDate to $null to allow for no date?